# What is a good tutorial for C++ policy-based class design?

Tags: c++, templates, policy-based-design

I have just started reading [Modern C++ Design Generic programming and Design Patterns Applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655997/modern-c-design-generic-programming-and-design-patterns-applied) and I am wondering if I need to go through some very basic tutorial on policy-based class design before I dive in. Will chapter 1 provide all I need to follow it?

I am already experienced with template usage (STL/boost/Poco) and writing template classes/methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my experience its pretty much a self contained book, as long as you know your way around C++.
This is kind of a silly question. Just dive in the book, if something's not clear, look it up. Why ask questions about chaper 1 when you can just read it and find out?
Fear is the mind-killer.